# Database connectionstring windows authentication but passing user and password

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I need some help.
I'm trying to connect to my database.
This is my connectionstring :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=KBV-SQL12-TEST\KBSQLSPTEST; Initial Catalog=KBSPT_aspnetmembership; User Id=KBOVDM01\KBSPT_EXTRANET; Password=SPExtr@n3t" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The user is an Active Directory user. 
When I go to my SQLServer and log on as KBSPT_EXTRANET, I can op the SQL Management Studio and connect to the database.

But in my application when I use the connectionstring mentionned above, I keep getting the message "Underlying provider failed on open".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a Windows account when the connection string is expecting a SQL Server user account.

Comment: And how do I change that? I'm using an Active Directory Account.

Comment: Create a SQL Server account with appropriate permissions to your database, and use it's username and password in place of where you have the Windows username and password. I think you need to Google for a basic tutorial, SO is more for specific problems not beginners guides. Here's an old one, but principles should hold:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx

Comment: Actually I'm not allowed to make any accounts. I should use the account which I mentionned in my connectionstring.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help with that